# Overriding Web API ApiControllerActionInvoker Causes Methods to run twice when exceptions thrown

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I recently ran into a problem where I was developing an API which talked to two data sources in some methods. The POST for a couple methods modified SQL data through the use of entity framework as well a data source using as an old SDK that was STA COM based. To get the STA COM SDK code to work correctly from within the API methods, I had to create method attributes that identified the methods as needing to be single threaded. I forced single threading by overriding the InvokeActionAsync() method from ApiControllerActionInvoker. If a method was not given an attribute to be single threaded, the overridden invoker simply used the normal base class InvokeActionAsync().

```
public class SmartHttpActionInvoker: ApiControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Determine whether action has attribute UseStaThread
        bool useStaThread = context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<UseStaThreadAttribute>().Any();

        // If it doesn't, simply return the result of the base method
        if (!useStaThread)
        {
            return base.InvokeActionAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        }

        // Otherwise, create an single thread and then call the base method
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask = Task.Factory.StartNewSta(() => base.InvokeActionAsync(context, cancellationToken).Result);

        return responseTask;
    }
}

public static class TaskFactoryExtensions
{
    private static readonly TaskScheduler _staScheduler = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1);

    public static Task<TResult> StartNewSta<TResult>(this TaskFactory factory, Func<TResult> action)
    {
        return factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _staScheduler);
    }
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
....
     config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionInvoker), new SmartHttpActionInvoker());
...
}
```

This worked well until I noticed something odd. My Logging database was logging duplicate records when a method NOT marked as single threaded was throwing a HttpResponseException back to the client. This behavior did not exist when the same method returned OK().

Debugging, I noticed the code execute in the API method, then reach the throw statement. The next line after the exception was thrown to be shown in debugger was the InvokeActionAsync() code I wrote. Following this the method was run again, in full, hitting the thrown exception, the action invoker, and then returning the result to the client. Effectively, it appears my use of overriding the InvokeActionAsync causes the Action invoker to be called twice somehow... but I am not sure how.

EDIT: Confirmed that the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId for the current thread when it is thrown and logged is different for each execution of the API method. So, this reinforces my belief two threads are being created instead of one. Still not sure why.

Anyone have any experience with overriding the InvokeActionAsync behavior that might be able to explain this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: May be you have another registration for `IHttpActionInvoker` added in your code? After that, if you do a `Replace`, your class will be called twice.

Comment: @VMAtm I am only registering this replace once in the code. The Register method which accepts the HttpConfiguration is the only place I am attempting any sort of service manipulation.

Comment: In addition I have created a new API project, only modified the config to replace the IHttpActionInvoker, and added my Invoker overidden code. Using the default Values controller, I modified it to throw an HTTPResponseException if the value is less than 1. The same problem presents itself. The method runs twice. So it is definitively not a artifact of some other part of my project, but something to do with overriding theInvokeActionAsync() method .

Comment: I think that the source of this issue is in base method call

Comment: @VMAtm That is the way I see examples listed in many places from various internet sources. Can you propose an alternative? I have attempted various other implementations that do not use the base.Invoke call, and all exhibit the same behavior.